# Specifying job titles in the resume

Tags: title, job-description

I have a case where I want to apply for a particular role which expects me to have a product manager background. While I do have the background, my job title in previous roles dont reflect that (I have been handling product management roles but my company likes to call the employees consultants).

Hence would be lead to issues later if **I put my title as product manager** though the actual title in my company was more like a UX Consultant ( I am concerned about background checks if I do get the role).